# python dictionary best practice

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to Python. I want to create a dictionary.
Each key will have three values.

Which is a **better** approach?:

1.One Dictionary like this:

```
dict = {'a': [value1, value2, value3], 'b': [value1, value2, value3], ...}
```

2.Three dictionaries like this:

```
dict1 = {'a': value1, 'b': value1}

dict2 = {'a': value2, 'b': value2}

dict3 = {'a': value3, 'b': value3}
```

Comment: I think it depends. If you'll be using only some of these values then probably the second option should be good. But I personally would use Option 1.

Comment: It all depends on the *use case*.  Both formats are valid and acceptable. That aside, choose another variable name other than `dict`, as you’re currently shadowing the builtin function.

Comment: I would say it is a matter of taste and depends on the context but the code should always be readable. So if the 3 values are tied together like x,y,z-coordinates, I would recommend a dict where the values are namedtuples so you know what each value represents. If you have `{'Peter': [2,32,91]}` you don't really know what is what.
Also when there are many methods that need all values it is bad if you always have to pass all dicts instead of one.
But if the values are independend, 3 dicts make more sense like `fibonaccis = {1: 1, 5: 8}`, `team_names = {1: 'Lakers', 5: 'Miami Heat'}`.

Comment: Using option 1 gives the flexibility of having lists (per key) of different lengths. Having multiple dictionaries (option 2) could become unwieldy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a single dictionary with lists as data saved inside it is most likely the best option.

Quoting your example you can access both the whole list or single elements with `dict['a']` or `dict['a'][x]` where *x* is *0,1,2*,etc.

In this way, you can also apply all the function you need to the whole list way easily like reordering etc.

Of course it always depend on the use case and the type of data you want/have to save and/or process.

Comment: Using the term “best” is highly subjective.  The ‘best’ solution is what fits the use-case.

Comment: @S3DEV that's why I've used "most likely" which is not 100% sure

Comment: One use-case I could image is that creating a dictionary from a list, like:
`[['a','b','c'],['a','b','c'],['a','b','c']]`.
I want store both the index of the list and the index of the sublist of each element
@S3DEV which one do you prefer?